# How to detect microphone permissions state

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, permissions, microphone

I'm looking to show different modals to the user to guide them to allow their permission when trying to use a microphone requiring task in my app - based on whether they have not yet been requested for microphone permissions, granted permissions, or blocked permissions.

How can I reliably find out which state of permissions the user is in? Preferably with an `onChange` handler to know if the user revokes their permission at any point and something that would work for Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

The inspiration comes from [voice.google.com](https://voice.google.com) where they show different screen on the call widget when trying to call the Google voice number with the microphone permission set to "ask", "allow", or "block".

I've gone through https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/permissions-api-for-the-web but I can't seem to find a solution for how I would like to implement this.

**Edit:**

```
<div id="button">Click me</div>
<script>
  const button = document.getElementById("button")
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true
      })
      .then(function(stream) {
        console.log('You let me use your mic!')
        console.log(stream)
        navigator.permissions.query({
          name: 'microphone'
        }, ).then(function(permissionStatus) {
          console.log("PermissionStatus: ", permissionStatus.state); // granted, denied, prompt
          permissionStatus.onchange = function() {
            console.log("Permission changed to " + this.state);
          }
        })
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err)
        console.log('No mic for you!')
      });
  })
  navigator.permissions.query({
      name: 'microphone'
    })
    .then(function(permissionStatus) {
      console.log("PermissionStatus: ", permissionStatus.state); // granted, denied, prompt
      permissionStatus.onchange = function() {
        console.log("Permission changed to " + this.state);
      }
    })

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name is "microphone" and you'll get "granted", "prompt" or "denied" as the state.
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/recording-audio#use_the_permissions_api_to_check_if_you_already_have_access

Comment: I tried doing exactly that but I won't get a response from the `onChange` and if I call it after allowing the permission I still get the "prompt" response. I'll edit the question to show what I've tried.

Comment: I pasted your code into codepen and it works when I click the button

Comment: No way! I just tried codepen and it works like a charm. For some reason, it doesn't work in jsfiddle or repl, super weird. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It doesn't work on Safari & Internet Explorer